# In databinding, how do I programmatically set the root view of my layout to become another complex layout?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make an error page for each of my activities where if there is a network error, it will show this error page. Some activities have two fragments, some have a Recycler view,some have a Toolbar, so on.

I'm trying to implement this showErrorPage() method in the BaseActivity class as a generic method for all activity that extend it.
I'm thinking I would get the root view using binding.getRoot() then I need some way to hide whatever that view is, and replace it with error_page.xml which the root view is layout as for all data binding and it contains a LinearLayout which includes TextView AND ImageView

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely not try to do it the way you mentioned, since it would be unnecessarily complicated. In fact, you should never have to do this, since this isn't the way such a simple interface should be designed. Instead, I would probably create a Fragment which inflates error_page.xml as its root View.

Another approach you could try is surrounding your error_page.xml with `<merge>` tags and using `<include>` tags in each of the layouts of the activities/fragments you want to show your error layout (see https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge). Make sure that your `<include>` is at the bottom of each layout.

Then in every layout containing your `<include>` tag, I would set `android:visibility="gone"`, `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, `android:layout_height="match_parent"` within the body of the include and give it an id. In your method `showErrorPage()`, you could then set the visibility of the included layout, using its id, to `View.VISIBLE`.